# MAAS networking

Tags: networking, maas

I installed MAAS and autopilot installed Openstack. I have VM instances running and reachable. My question is i would like to add additional VLAN's now to put VM instances in different networks. I noticed that in MAAS setup for a node network setup VLAN is untagged always and i am not able to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question it might help someone else... In the meantime updated the os on the MAAS to 16.04 which in turn updated MAAS components and bumped MAAS to 2.0.

Under networking tab i added all the VLANS i had. Then updated each interface under nodes with the correct VLAN data. Tried to run sudo openstack-install again. It fails. Google and found out no more openstack-install in 16.04. Now you need to use conjure-up openstack. This fails miserably not matter the options i try :(. Also no autopilot when you use conjure-up :(.